# Conditional formula based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a simple Excel sheet to track customer debt. I have created a sheet called `Customers` and in there I have a list of customers.

[image: customer debt]

Then for each month of the year, I have another sheet, e.g. `April`, `May` ...etc. `April` looks like this right now:

[image: month]

Inside the **Remaining Debt** cell for each customer, let's pick the first cell, so `D2`, I would like a formula that looks at the customer name `A2`, and **if** the customer name matches what's in `April!B2` then the amount should be added.

The formula needs to work for all entries in the `April` sheet. To be honest, I am not sure if that is the best way to go about this, but I know this is one way.

If the formula is correct, the **Remaining Debt** cell will have `-£1100`. In terms of math formula, I think this will work:

`debt amount + (all customer A activity in April and all other months)`

I'm not sure how that translates to Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SUMIF` for this. In `D2` enter:

```
=C2+SUMIF(April!B:B,A2,April!D:D)
```

And populate down

Comment: Thank you @cybernetic.nomad, though I believe it should be `=C2+SUMIF(April!B:B,A2,April!D:D)`. This now works for April, but only April. How do I extend this to look at the other sheets too? Is it a matter of adding another `SUMIF` for each month sheet?

Comment: Yes, you need a `SUMIF` for each sheet